# Debian based server picks wrong network as gateway

Tags: debian, routing, gateway

I'm configuring own server to act as router. It has three interfaces, two cable and wifi.

Following [this article](http://agentoss.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/creating-a-wireless-access-point-with-debian-linux/) to configure access point. After setting bridge i have problem with default gateway. System always chooses bridge as gateway what is wrong.

Interfaces are: eth0 -> link do my ISP (DHCP - dynamic address), eth1 -> internal network, wlan0 -> wifi.

eth1 and wlan0 are bridged.

Some data:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.22.11   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 zbr0
192.168.11.64   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.22.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 zbr0


eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:be:f7:09:67:7a
      inet addr:192.168.11.77  Bcast:192.168.11.127  Mask:255.255.255.192
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:245 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:18860 (18.4 KiB)  TX bytes:1559 (1.5 KiB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:be:f7:09:67:7b
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:367 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:254 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:62760 (61.2 KiB)  TX bytes:37744 (36.8 KiB)
      Interrupt:18 Memory:f7c00000-f7c20000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:190 (190.0 B)  TX bytes:190 (190.0 B)

zbr0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:be:f7:09:67:7b
      inet addr:192.168.22.11  Bcast:192.168.22.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:285 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:245 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:32960 (32.1 KiB)  TX bytes:35426 (34.5 KiB)
```

How to set gateway via interface not an IP address?

Interfaces configuration:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual

auto zbr0
iface zbr0 inet static
bridge_ports eth1
address 192.168.22.11
netmask 255.255.255.128
network 192.168.22.0
broadcast 192.168.22.127
gateway 192.168.22.11
```

Comment: Can you show us your `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration?

Comment: added to question.

Comment: I think it should suffice to delete the `gateway` entry in your `interfaces` file. Since you retrieve the IP address for `eth0` over DHCP it should establish the default route through `eth0` appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the default route that is in the routing table and replace it with something like `route add default gw 192.168.11.1 eth0`

Comment: Useless for me, IP address on eth0 is dynamic so i would have to change that route every time when it changes.

Comment: The address in that command is the actual gateway address. You are simply telling all packets not destined for a known network or host to be funneled out the `eth0` interface, to the address specified in the command. Did you try it?

Comment: Also, your interfaces file has the gateway set just as the routing table describes.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, i thought that gateway parameter is for dhcp clients on that network.